# replacing array index value

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array in which there are users values are stored that will be sent to execute(); function for mysqli query.
So, I want the index values to be replaced.

Now what I have done here is used str_replace(); function to do so within foreach loop but the problem is that how I will get the updated array?

```
$fields = array(
 'field_id' => '123', 
 'field_name' => 'test_name' 
);

foreach ($fields as $key => $field) {
  $val  = str_replace($key, $key, ':'.$key);
  $data = array();
  $data[$val] = $field;
} 

//I only got the value for the last index 1st is not there
print_r($data);

//output which I am expecting will be the following
$fields = array(
  ':field_id' => '123',
  ':field_name' => 'test_name'
);
```

Please let me know if any one could help me out

Comment: I don't think str_replace will do what you want. Why don't u just do sth like this:
`$fields[':'.$key] = $field;
unset $fields[$key];`

Comment: @LuciaAngermüller let me try this

Comment: `str_replace(searchterm, replacement, subject)`, you're doing it wrong, probably ... also, you should create the *empty* array before the loop, not inside, or only the last entry will remain ...

Comment: Use the Version from Object Manipulator. It's an even cleaner Solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The objective is to prepend each key with a colon (:).
>
> This can be achieved by looping through the main array, modifying each
>   key and filling these key value pairs in **$newArray**.

We can loop through **$fields**, fetch each key and prepend it with ':', and make this the key of our **$newArray**. i.e field_id becomes :field_id, field_name becomes :field_name.. and so on.

The values are copied from **$fields** and put in **$newArray** as it is.

```
$newArray = array();
foreach ($fields as $key => $field) {
     $newArray[':'.$key] = $field;
}
```

Comment: Thank You it worked for me but I did not understood what actually you did here

Comment: okay so when ever we define an array like $a = array(); what ever we store in $a will be converted to array automatically

Comment: Thank you very much for the solutions and explanations

Comment: Actually, that syntax would mean we are declaring a new variable of type array. If a variable with a same name was already created earlier, they would be reset as a blank array. So, it's better to use this syntax for these kinds of operations.